# Magento 2: How to add edit cart option on order summary on checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want to add custom link in order summary on checkout page in magento. I have tried several options but doesn't work.

Is there any solution for this.

Like the following image:
[image]

Comment: Have you got any solution for this as I am also struggling with this same issue?

Comment: Not yet, I have implemented using jquery

Comment: Have you any solution for the same issue @ Amrit Pal Singh.
if yes please help me

Answer (score 2):

Question is too old but i am providing solution here so if someone have encountered this issue / requirement.

To add **Edit** link on cart summary block, you have to make changes in **web/template/summary/cart-items.html** file of Magento_Checkout :

Copy `module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/cart-items.html` and paste this in your Theme's `Magento_Ccheckout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/cart-items.html`.

And add below code block :

```
<div class="edit-summary">
    <span class="cart-summary-edit-link">
        <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: cartUrl}">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit Cart'"></span>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Where you want to add Cart summary link.

After making changes **delete** your **var/view_processed/pub** and **pub/static/frontend** folders and deploy static-content again.

**NOTE** : if you add this block within `data-role=title` div it will add the link but will not work as click event will not work on URL , because click event is being used for cart summary accordion ( open close ). solution is tested with Magento 2.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Copy `module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/cart-items.html` and paste this in your Theme's `Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/cart-items.html`

Remove the condition from View and Edit cart div

```
<div class="actions-toolbar" >
<div class="secondary">
    <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: cartUrl}">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'View and Edit Cart'"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```